# Swift optional for nested array

Tags: swift, swift5

I am creating a TicTacToe game on swift using Nested array. I am creating a nested array of string. How do I check an optional for nil here and only enter symbol only if it is nil. Explain me the concept of optionals here please.

```
var board: [[String]]?
func placeSymbol(position: (Int, Int), symbol: String) {
  if(position.0 < 3 && position.1 < 3) {
    if (board?[position.0][position.1]) != nil {
        board?[position.0][position.1] = symbol
    }
  }
    print(board)
}

placeSymbol(position: (1, 1), symbol: "X")
```

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an array of optional strings we create an array of optional strings

```
var board: [[String?]]
```

We also remember to initialize the array in some way, e.g. like this (although it is only a demo)

```
board = [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

And now we are free to try to unwrap our optionals and check the result of the unwrapping

```
if let cell = board[position.0][position.1] {
} else {
    // our cell logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you know the size of board, you need to initialize the `board` `Array` with all `nil` values.

```
var board = [[String?]](repeating: [String?](repeating: nil, count: 3), count: 3)
```

The initialization is required because in an `Array` you cannot add the element at an `index` if the `index` doesn't exist currently. It will throw a runtime exception.

Now, in `placeSymbol(position:symbol:)` method add the `symbol` after checking whether the value at `board[position.0][position.1]` is `nil`, i.e.

```
func placeSymbol(position: (Int, Int), symbol: String) {
    if board[position.0][position.1] == nil {
        board[position.0][position.1] = symbol
    }
    print(board)
}
```